# Associate expiry days with the SharePoint document library's shared files

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file, share

When I click share from SharePoint document library files to users directly as per below then is there a way to set expiry days for those shared files to users?

As per now mechanism of email getting triggered by SharePoint itself once I share to users directly but how to manage expiry days for those sharing of files or any workaround appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can add one Shared date column and update it when you share it with a user. Then associate a scheduled Power Automate which runs daily to check daily whether it has been 'X' days while the file is shared. If the condition falls true, then inherit the document library permission for those files.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.appreciate if sample steps to inherit permissions for files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a schedular Power Automate
2. Set `SharedDays` variable (e.g. you want to remove the sharing of the files which were shared 'X' days ago from today. Here for example, it is 2). Put a minus sign before it to calculate the date of X days ago from today.
3. Get the `SharedDateLimit` variable which will have date of X days ago.

[image]

4. Now get the files whose `SharedDate` column value is less than or equal to `SharedDateLimit`.

[image]

5. Now add `Apply to each` condition to iterate through each file.
6. In `Apply to each` condition, make another HTTP call to restore the permission inheritance of each file using `ID`.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Awesome.Worked as expected